# Unzip .gz file in windows batch script using 7zip

Tags: windows, script, 7-zip, extract

I have 7 zip installed on windows machine. I have to extract .gz files into .txt files. I am not able to find a suitable command to do that. I tried below :

7za e %SFTP_INDIR%\DFUView.20150531060116.gz -o D:\Batch\Batch_FWK\data\in\DFUView.txt

Got errors using this - '7za' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. Need help.

Comment: Make sure 7za.exe is in your path, or in the directory in which you're running the command.

Comment: I tried with this command again :

D:\Batch\7-Zip\7z.exe %SFTP_INDIR%\DFUView.20150531060116.gz -o D:\Batch\Batch_FWK\data\in\DFUView.txt

and this gave error : 

Command Line Error:
Too short switch:
-o

Comment: You've specified a switch for 7z but where's the command? Type 7za /? or read the manual.